# Using All Cap letters for web site Headings

Tags: website-design, typography, header

I am working on a redesigning . I am looking to use capital letters for section headers. Do you think this will be a good approach from UX point of view ?

Thanks

Comment: Do you mean ALL CAPITALS or do you mean what is normally called Title Case? Where (which country) are most of the site users?

Comment: I meant ALL CAPITALS . and More users are from 

Japan
Germany
Italy
United States
Thailand

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The legibility decreases when using only caps (because the word has no defining shape anymore, it's more of a horizontal bar). Since legibility affects the time it takes to scan words, it does have a (small) impact on usability. However, all-caps can(!) look really stylish and if your users pay a lot of attention to style, this might just improve their experience on your site.

Comment: I would say it *might* be fine for a single heading, but never in a menu (Visual Studio comes with a menu all in caps now, and it is horrible to scan for something).

Comment: The answer is correct, but would be great if you can provide a reference (for the legibility claim - it's out there).

Comment: A study was done by Miles Tinker showing that all-capital text retarded speed of reading from 9.5 to 19.0 percent for the 5 and 10-minute time limits, and 13.9 percent for the whole 20-minute period. - Miles Tinker, Bases for Effective Reading, 1965, Minneapolis, Lund Press. p. 136.

Answer (score 3):

Personally I find Small Cap headings (first letter larger than the rest) more readable among all capital heading.

[image]